# javadoc with -Xdoclint:none producing useful warnings missing when switch is absent?

Tags: javadoc

I have discovered an odd behavior in Javadoc while upgrading to Java 8.  We have a lot of code that is rejected by the stricter Java 8 Javadoc.  As a result, I introduced the -Xdoclint:none switch to our builds as a temporary workaround as suggested by http://blog.joda.org/2014/02/turning-off-doclint-in-jdk-8-javadoc.html.  In so doing, Javadoc started reporting warnings that were not reported when the switch was absent.  The warnings seem to be valid warnings of the sort that are ordinarily reported - it is not clear to me why this switch is affecting the generation of those warnings:  Example: "Parameter  is documented more than once."

Here is a specific example.  Consider the following version of the basic 'Hello, world' Java program:

```
public class Hello {
    /**
     * Entry point for Hello class.
     * @param args is the arg list
     * @param args is documented more than once - gradle catches - ant?
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

From the directory containing Hello.java, invoke Javadoc as shown:

```
path> javadoc -quiet Hello.java

path> javadoc -quiet -Xdoclint:none Hello.java
Hello.java:7: warning - Parameter "args" is documented more than once.
1 warning

path>
```

Does anyone else see these results?  Is this correct?  Why does turning doclint off cause this (proper) warning to be reported, when it is missed in the default case when doclint is on?

In my case I am testing on a 64-bit Windows 7 Enterprise (Service Pack 1) workstation using Java 1.8.0_51-b16 for X64.

Comment: Not reproducible using OpenJDK 1.8.0_66 in Debian Linux: warning is issued regardless of whether `-Xdoclint:none` is present or not. Have you tried more recent OpenJDK/Oracle JDK builds?

Comment: I reproduced the issue with the more recent Oracle JDK 1.8.0_65-b17, again on Windows 64-bit.

Comment: I am seeing something similar to this today. Using gradle on Windows 64bit with Amazon Corretto (11 and 17), we had `-Xdoclint:off` and were still seeing some warnings being output. Switching to `-Xdoclint:all` doesn't make these things disappear, but causes them to be reported as errors instead. The errors contain all the previous warnings, and some new issues. There are also warnings, but they are a completely new set and are less significant than the things previously reported as warnings.